# Create multiple label over the multiple ellipse

Tags: c#, label, controls, ellipse

I have 6 `ellipse` and 6 `label`. I want to add `label`s over the `ellipse`. 2 of `label`s is OK but the others not.

*In debug mode there is no error.*

Here is the code:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int locY = 200, locX = 10, i = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                locX += 40;
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                    locY += 30;
                    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 10);
                    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, new Rectangle(locX, locY, 10, 10));
                    Label label = new Label();
                    label.Text = i.ToString();
                    label.Location = new Point(locX,locY);
                    label.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                    Controls.Add(label);
                    i++;
                }
                locY = 200;
            }
        }
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: 1) you really should not create any controls inside a Paint event, esp. as you will not have control over when and how often it will be called. 2) why use labels when you can simply drawstring the texts?

Comment: So you said I need to create these label into the ``Form1_Load`` event, right? This is example, I want to create label how much user want.

Comment: Agreeing with @TaW.  Every time you paint the screen you will be creating 6 labels, whose lifetime is bound to the innermost `for` loop.  As each of those loops finished, the label you just created will be eligible for garbage collection (which, remember, is behaves differently in release code than in debug code).  You never dispose them, so your process handle count will just keep going up.

Comment: It doesn't really matter when you create them but you need to make sure you only create them __once__. Your code doesn't control that! You could put it into an if block that test if they already are there.. Hint: Add this line to the end of your paint code: `Console.WriteLine(this.Controls.Count + " controls so far.");`

Comment: But, you can just draw text, roughly the same way you draw the ellipses.  Keep track of what you want to draw in each circle, and when paint comes, draw the ellipse and then draw the text on top

Comment: Thanks for advices, I'll try.

Comment: _the label you just created will be eligible for garbage collection_ Um, no they are in the form's Controls collection so they will persist!

Comment: Oh, I missed the Controls.Add statement.  Oops!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also create that Pen outside of the loop and make sure to dispose of it.

Here's an example using DrawString() as described in the comments:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

    int locY = 200, locX = 10, i = 0;
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 10))
    {               
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            locX += 40;
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                locY += 30;
                Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(locX, locY, 10, 10);
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, rc);

                SizeF szF = e.Graphics.MeasureString(i.ToString(), this.Font);
                Rectangle rc2 = new Rectangle(new Point(rc.Left + rc.Width / 2, rc.Top + rc.Height / 2), new Size(1, 1));
                rc2.Inflate((int)szF.Width, (int)szF.Height);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(i.ToString(), this.Font, Brushes.Black, rc2, sf);

                i++;
            }
            locY = 200;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that using Labels may have its merits, e.g. they are clickable.  Also: If one only uses simple colors using Brushes.color or Pens.color spares us disposing/using..